# return void* pointer from function into other function parameter

Tags: c, list, generics, pointers, void

I'm, trying to build a generic list that handles Element(s)
each object (pointer to struct) in the program should use this list,

that's the definition for void*, from now on it's Element.
and the add function signature:

```
typedef void* Element;
void AddElementToList(List thisList , Element toAdd);
```

and the create user function and the user definition:

```
typedef struct FacebookUser_t* User;
User CreateUser(char* const lineToSplit);
```

that's how i call the function:

```
AddElementToList(thisServer->UsersList , (Element)CreateUser(line));
```

while debugging the create user function doing good and values assigned to it, just after it return it seems that the object become empty and then at the add element it crushes.
that's the return :

```
return toAdd;
```

'toAdd' it's User type.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't tell what's wrong without seeing the relevant parts of CreateUser and AddElementToList. Sounds like you're mis-using stack-based objects, but could be anything.

Comment: Hiding pointers behind `typedef`s is a bad idea; the semantics of pointers are fundamentally different, and hiding that can lead to code that is confusing to read.

Comment: Btw, `const` in the above makes `lineToSplit`, the pointer, not what it points to, constant. You probably want it the other way around: `char const* lineToSplit` or `const char* lineToSplit` (they're equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without more information, but you need to watch out for object scope:
- your `CreateUser` function has to allocate memory for a `FacebookUser_t` object on the heap, using `malloc` or similar, returning a pointer to that (type `User`; that's why @OliCharlesworth is warning about hiding pointers behind a typedef: `User` is not a user-object, and does not allocate memory).

Your last line suggests another possible problem. You indicated `toAdd` to be a parameter to the function `AddElementToList`, then you talk about returning 'toAdd', but the function is of type 'void'. Something is confusing here IMHO, and you might want to review those sections.